# Penning Trap Anode

Tags: electric-fields, electrical-engineering, metals

I am looking to confirm my logic around how the anode in a Penning trap is able to reflect/contain protons via an electric field.

My logic is that the anode is an excitinged metal such as (Metal)2+, and hence the atom and metal has a net charge of +2.

Given a large number of free protons are required to be reflected by the anode, the anode must have a voltage applied and therefore the metal will become excited, which will provide at any point a positive charge equal to or greater than the incoming free proton, hence reflecting it away from ever actually touching the metal?

My only point of logic which seems to be flawed in my eyes is if the density of the metal or the charge density of the metal to be more exact was not enough to stop the free protons. This would cause the free protons to reach the metal anodes atom's outer electrons and hence attraction would occur potentially, meaning that the anode would be destroyed, instead of the protons being reflected, though I am unsure of how accurate this is.

Any clarification of correct logic would be great to help me understand how the anode can actually reflect protons in a penning trap.

Comment: The anode is at some potential, sure. It doesn’t take that many charges to build up a large potential, depending on the capacitance of the electrode.

Comment: Hi @Jon Custer, does this mean that the free protons will be reflected due to the large potential, given that the anode's charge density is high enough? Is that logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer your question in detail, since to me it seems there are a few misconceptions hidden inside. For further questions, I propose that you try to simplify your question even further, for example, by thinking/asking about a proton between two plates of a capacitor instead of a Penning trap.

> I am looking to confirm my logic around how the anode in a Penning trap is able to reflect/contain protons via an electric field.

Note that the electric field only contains the proton along the $z$-axis! Along the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, the electric field pulls the proton away from the trap center. Here the magnetic field comes into play, which forces the proton onto a complicated orbit around the trap center. But it is an unstable orbit -- over time, the proton can drift away! In good traps, this happens very, very slowly: It would take at least thousands of years, if not much, much longer, for the proton to drift into the trap electrodes.

> My logic is that the anode is an excitinged metal such as (Metal)2+, and hence the atom and metal has a net charge of +2.

I disagree. The metal surfaces are not in ionized in any way. Metals simply allow charges to move quite freely throughout them. It is probably best to avoid thinking about individual atoms of the metal or discrete surface-charges. Instead, I propose to think of the metal electrodes as smooth surfaces that have a defined voltage. But if you are interested on the number of additional charges on the metal: You can use the formula

$$ Q = C \cdot U $$

Typical values for a proton trap are $C = 10\,\text{pF}$ and $U = 10 \,\text{V}$, which works out to $10^{-10}$ coulombs or, in other words, something like 600 million electrons. This number does *not* depend on how many protons you store in the Penning trap! It's the same whether you store 1 proton or 1000 protons in the trap.

> Given a large number of free protons are required to be reflected by the anode, the anode must have a voltage applied and therefore the metal will become excited, which will provide at any point a positive charge equal to or greater than the incoming free proton, hence reflecting it away from ever actually touching the metal?

I'm not sure what you mean with "excited". The voltage does not excite the metal, it simply causes some extra electrons to flow into the electrode (or flow away from the electrode). The electrode does not need to have a greater charge than the proton in order to repel it -- any positive charge suffices, as long as the proton moves slow enough. (Well, technically we have to consider image-charges, which are always attractive, but that's a discussion for another day.)

> My only point of logic which seems to be flawed in my eyes is if the density of the metal or the charge density of the metal to be more exact was not enough to stop the free protons. This would cause the free protons to reach the metal anodes atom's outer electrons and hence attraction would occur potentially, meaning that the anode would be destroyed, instead of the protons being reflected, though I am unsure of how accurate this is.

The charge density of metals can be controlled very accurately by soldering a wire to them and setting a precise voltage! As a rule of thumb: A grounded electrode has exactly as many positive as negative charges. (This is not always true, because you are free to define your ground-potential to be anything you like, and because of "image charges", which are comparatively small and are something we can ignore for now).

Also: It takes a lot more to destroy an electrode than a few protons crashing into it.

Note that any proton with sufficient energy will escape the trap and crash into the electrodes. When you supply a low voltage on the trap electrodes, then the trap is "shallow" and can only contain low-energy protons. If you supply a very high voltage, then the trap will become unstable (the "stability limit"). For typical proton traps ($1\,\text{mm}$ to $10\,\text{mm}$ in size and a magnetic field of $1\,\text{T}$ to $5\,\text{T}$), you use voltages on the order of $1\,\text{V}$ to $100\,\text{V}$.